# Ipad App: How to react on roatation?

Tags: ipad

I have a few labels on my first Ipad App.
How to make them rotating?
When I rotate the IPad, the Label is still the same position as before, it dowsn't rotate with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is pretty much page 1 of the documentation. Apple wrote it for a reason.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW23